# Chrome remote debugging: empty inspect tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I'm using Google Chrome v35.0.1916.114 and followed the steps to enable remote debugging on my Samsung Trend Plus GT-S7580 which runs Chrome v35.0.1916.122.

I can effectively view the opened tabs, close them and all, but inspecting a tab gives me a blank console.

Any reason why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 26):

I have faced same problem. In my case I have found that version of chrome browser on windows system was 44.x but on android mobile device has 54.x. I just updated my windows chrome. And everything started working fine.

Comment: It was a great help!

Comment: Same problem... device was version 65 and computer was version 64. Updated the computer and it started working.

Comment: This turned out to be true for me, even though it was only a very minor version difference, 94.0.4606.72 v. 94.0.4606.76. On the Android side, I had to specifically go to the app manager in Settings and tap Updates Available; just going to the Chrome app in Google Play did not work.

Answer (score 13):

Remote debugging with Chrome downloads files from https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com. 
Test your connection: Try to open https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com
If it doesn't work, that's why you're getting an empty window.
In this case, maybe you need a VPN.

Answer (score 5):

I had the crasiest workaround:

Press CTRL+SHIFT+I, which opens a new developer tool for the developer tool.
Go to console and run: window.location.reload()

This reloads the first developer window and attaches to the original process.

Comment: Didn't need a new Developer Tool, simply the reload fixed it. Thanks for that!

Comment: This is probably the same as clicking the reload icon which looks like a circular arrow. Did not help in my case :-(

Answer (score 2):

I have the problem even with Chrome 46, here is my workaround...

On the blank/empty Dev Tools window press '**Ctr+Shift+i**'. This opens a **2nd** Dev Tools window. 
You will see an error in the console “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExtensions'” and on the right one of these 2 links :

A) "VM45:72"
=> bad luck. Close 2nd window and try again.

B) "**(program):72**"
=> that’s it. click on the link "(program):72" and  the 1st debug window will work again !

It may take one to 10 times before the "(program):72" appears

Answer (score 2):

Check with desktop chrome 
1) Goto help  => About Google Chrome

Check with version number

Check with Mobile Chrome go to Help & feedback
1) right side option => version info

Check with version number

**If both are same ... Remote device debugging will work**

Answer (score 1):

Try using chrome Version 37.0.2041.4 canary or latest on your computer. I just had the same issue with the version you have but installed the latest canary and got it working. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

open **chrome://appcache-internals/** and clear the manifest cache , then reload the resource

Comment: When I go there, I see:
`Application Cache`
`Instances in: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Storage/ext/longalphastring/def (0)`
`Instances in: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Storage/ext/longalphastring/def (0)`
`Instances in: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default (0)`
What is the manifest cache, how is it cleared, and what resource do you mean?

Comment: 404 - seems they've since removed it :/

Answer (score 1):

#### No cross browsing !

Jumping in quite late here, just had a similar issue. Turns out, in my case, I was using Chrome on my computer and Brave on my cellphone. Important to note that Chrome will allow to inspect Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

Ignore blank page and first visit

http://localhost:9222/json

then check `devtoolsFrontendUrl` from the JSON and go to

http://localhost:9222/

I wrote a post about how to setup Chrome Remote Debugging which covers this fix https://devforth.io/blog/chrome-remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enabled proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can remotely focus and close tabs on the mobile Chrome that were opened directly on the phone. I can also "inspect" those, with a nice screencast on the dev pc.

What does not work is entering a URL on the dev pc and click Open. That new URL is added to the list of tabs on the dev pc, but is not really opened on the phone. The Inspect button on that tab does not show a screencast, or just the blank one that OP asked about.

The solution is to enter the desired URL directly on the phone, then select that tab remotely on the dev pc to get a nice screen cast and debuggin situation.